# R function works with some dataframes but not others?

Tags: r, function

I've a data frame that summarises the number of missing and non-missing observations in a data frame that is passed to it[1].  I then have been asked to test for differences between two treatment arms in the data I have (personally I disagree with the need or utility of doing so, but its what I've been asked to do).  So I've written a small function to do this...

```
quick.test <- function(x, y){
  chisq   <- chisq.test(x = x,  y = y)
  fisher  <- fisher.test(x = x, y = y)
  results <- cbind(chisq  = chisq$statistic,
                   df     = chisq$parameter,
                   p      = chisq$p.value,
                   fisher = fisher$p.value)
  results
}
```

I then use apply() to pass the relevant columns to this function as follows...

```
apply(miss.t1, 1, function(x) quick.test(x[2:3], x[4:5]))
```

This is fine for the above specified miss.t1 data frame, but I'm working with time-series data and have three time-points I wish to summarise so have miss.t2 and miss.t3 (each of which is summarising the number of present/missing data for each time point, and have been created in the same manner using the function described in [1]).

miss.t2 fails with the following error...

```
apply(miss.t2, 1, function(x) quick.test(x[2:3], x[4:5]))
Error in chisq.test(x = x, y = y) : 
  'x' and 'y' must have at least 2 levels
```

My initial thought was that one of the columns had a missing value for some reason, but this doesn't appear to be the case...

```
> describe(miss.t2)
miss.t2 

 5  Variables      171  Observations
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
variable 
      n missing  unique 
    171       0     171 

lowest : Abtotal   Abyn      agg_ment  agg_phys  All.score
highest: z_pf      z_re      z_rp      z_sf      z_vt      
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
nmiss.1 
      n missing  unique    Mean 
    171       0       4   8.649 

0 (6, 4%), 8 (9, 5%), 9 (153, 89%), 10 (3, 2%) 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
npresent.1 
      n missing  unique    Mean 
    171       0       4   9.351 

8 (3, 2%), 9 (153, 89%), 10 (9, 5%), 18 (6, 4%) 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
nmiss.2 
      n missing  unique    Mean 
    171       0       4   10.65 

0 (6, 4%), 11 (160, 94%), 12 (4, 2%), 13 (1, 1%) 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
npresent.2 
      n missing  unique    Mean 
    171       0       4   14.35 

12 (1, 1%), 13 (4, 2%), 14 (160, 94%), 25 (6, 4%) 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Next thing I tried was trying subsets of miss.t2 by taking head(miss.t2, n=XX) and it works fine upto row 54...

```
> apply(head(miss.t2, n=53), 1, function(x) quick.test(x[2:3], x[4:5]))
     1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28
[1,] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
[2,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
[3,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
[4,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
     29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53
[1,]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
[2,]  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
[3,]  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
[4,]  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
> apply(head(miss.t2, n=54), 1, function(x) quick.test(x[2:3], x[4:5]))
Error in chisq.test(x = x, y = y) : 
  'x' and 'y' must have at least 2 levels
> miss.t2[54,]
   variable nmiss.1 npresent.1 nmiss.2 npresent.2
54      psq      10          8      11         14
> traceback()
5: stop("'x' and 'y' must have at least 2 levels") at #2
4: chisq.test(x = x, y = y) at #2
3: quick.test(x[2:3], x[4:5])
2: FUN(newX[, i], ...)
1: apply(head(miss.t2, n = 54), 1, function(x) quick.test(x[2:3], 
       x[4:5]))
```

Similarly with the 'bottom' of the data frame the last 26 rows are parsed fine, but not the 27th from last...

```
> apply(tail(miss.t2, n=26), 1, function(x) quick.test(x[2:3], x[4:5]))
     146 147 148 149 150 151 152 153 154 155 156 157 158 159 160 161 162 163
[1,]   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
[2,]   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
[3,]   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
[4,]   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
     164 165 166 167 168 169 170 171
[1,]   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
[2,]   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
[3,]   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
[4,]   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
There were 26 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
> apply(tail(miss.t2, n=27), 1, function(x) quick.test(x[2:3], x[4:5]))
Error in chisq.test(x = x, y = y) : 
  'x' and 'y' must have at least 2 levels
In addition: Warning message:
In chisq.test(x = x, y = y) : Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect

> miss.t2[118,]
    variable nmiss.1 npresent.1 nmiss.2 npresent.2
118     sf16       9          9      11         14
```

I can't see anything wrong with these two lines that means they should fail and the traceback() shown above doesn't reveal anything useful (to my mind).

Can anyone offer any suggestions as to why or where things are going wrong?

Many thanks in advance,

Neil

EDIT : Formatted reply to Vincent Zoonekynd ...

I opted for the chisq.test(x = x, y = y) version described in ?chisq.test(), using cbind() as you suggest to produce a matrix results in 
    Error in sum(x) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument.

Putting print statements and showing the length of x and y results in the same error, but shows the values and lenghts as being...

```
> miss.t2.res <- data.frame(t(apply(miss.t2, 1, function(x) quick.test(x[2:3], x[4:5])))) 
[1] "Your x is : 9" "Your x is : 9" 
[1] 2    ### < Length of x
[1] "Your y is : 11" "Your y is : 14"
[1] 2    ### < Length of y
Error in chisq.test(x = x, y = y) : 'x' and 'y' must have at least 2 levels
```

EDIT 2 : Thanks to Vincent Zoonekynd pointers the problem was that because the counts were identical for two cells the call to chisq.test() treats these as factors and collapses them.  The solution was to modify the quick.test() function and coerce the arguments that are being passed into a matrix, so the function that worked is now....

```
quick.test <- function(x, y){
  chisq   <- chisq.test(rbind(as.numeric(x), as.numeric(y)))
  fisher  <- fisher.test(rbind(as.numeric(x), as.numeric(y)))
  results <- cbind(chisq  = chisq$statistic,
                   df     = chisq$parameter,
                   p      = chisq$p.value,
                   fisher = fisher$p.value)
  results
}
```

Many thanks for the help & pointers Vincent, very much appreciated.

[1] http://gettinggeneticsdone.blogspot.co.uk/2011/02/summarize-missing-data-for-all.html

Comment: You could try options(error=utils::recover), to examine the values of x and y when the error occurs, or add print statements before the call to chisq.test, or provide some sample data, so that we can reproduce your problem. But shoudn't the call to `chisq.test` be `chisq.test(cbind(x,y))`?

Comment: Added details to original message, thanks for the quick reply.  Strange thing is it works fine with subsets of miss.t2 and fine with what appear to be identical data frames miss.t1 and miss.t3.

Comment: According to `?chisq.test`, if you use `chisq.test(x,y)`, the arguments are interpreted as factors, not as frequency tables: `x=c(9,9)` corresponds to two observations of the same value (the actual value, `9`, is not used).

Comment: Ah, ha that sounds like it could cause problems, I hadn't understood that from reading the help (hadn't read the finer 'Details' section where that is stated, foolish me) , will have a go at tweaking the code.

Comment: @slackline, if your second edit solves your problem, why not post it as an answer and mark the answer as accepted. That will help clean up the queue of unanswered questions under the R tag and will help other users who might have a similar problem.

Comment: @mrdwab : hadn't realised that it remained under "unanswered"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution suggested by Vincent Zoonkeynd in the comments above, was to modify the quick.test() function and coerce the arguments that are being passed into a matrix, so the function that worked is now....

```
quick.test <- function(x, y){
  chisq   <- chisq.test(rbind(as.numeric(x), as.numeric(y)))
  fisher  <- fisher.test(rbind(as.numeric(x), as.numeric(y)))
  results <- cbind(chisq  = chisq$statistic,
                   df     = chisq$parameter,
                   p      = chisq$p.value,
                   fisher = fisher$p.value)
  results
}
```